# Replacing Part of a String

Tags: php, str-replace

Consider the code below...

```
    ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0] = 'translated to the left and down,';
    $trans_1 = str_replace("left", "right", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
    $trans_1 = str_replace("right", "left", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
    $trans_1 = str_replace("up", "down", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
    $trans_1 = str_replace("down", "up", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
    echo $trans_1;
```

I'm trying to replace "left" with "right" (and vice versa) and "up" with "down" (and vice versa).  The `echo` keeps coming out as **translated to the left and up** when it should be **translated to the `right` and up**

Any ideas?

Comment: @Lurkers: -2 for what?

Comment: OK, I drew that phrasing from old close reasons and maybe exactly this reception was why they were removed. So once again and more specifically. You have some code. You describe how you want it to behave, even with example of input, desired output and real output. So far so good. Now the bad things. This is not [MCTRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not minimal, not complete. Also the close reasons I mentioned are in some form still on [help/on-topic] on-topic page. Attempted solutions, why they didn’t work… [Ask] help suggests “Introduce the problem before you post any code”. Read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always pass the original string to `str_replace()` and overwrite the same variable that stores the result. Thus only the ůast substitution takes place.

```
${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0] = 'translated to the left and down,';
$trans_1 = str_replace("left", "right", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_1 = str_replace("right", "left", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_1 = str_replace("up", "down", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_1 = str_replace("down", "up", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]); // only this is really performed, the rest is overwritten
echo $trans_1;
```

Try

```
echo strtr(${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0], array(
    'left' => 'right',
    'right' => 'left',
    'up' => 'down',
    'down' => 'up'
));
```

Comment: Ok.  How do you get around this?

Comment: @gtilflm FYI it solves another bug in the code. Even if you made all the substitutions on one string consecutively, you would rewrite `left` to `right` and the this new `right` back to `left`. `strtr()` solves this by applying substitutions all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your code from this:

```
$trans_1 = str_replace("left", "right", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_1 = str_replace("right", "left", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_1 = str_replace("up", "down", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_1 = str_replace("down", "up", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0];
echo $trans_1;
```

to:

```
$trans_1 = str_replace("left", "right", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_2 = str_replace("right", "left", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_1 = str_replace("up", "down", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0]);
$trans_2 = str_replace("down", "up", ${"transformation_" . $image_selector}[0];p
echo $trans_1;
echo $trans_2;
```

`$trans_1` will give the output `translated to the right and down`

`$trans_2` will give the output `translated to the left and up`